# How to replace the default web api model validation with Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, fluentvalidation

```
[Validator(typeof(ProductDetailsRequestDTO))]
    public class ProductDetailsRequestDTO
    {
        public int ArticleGroup { get; set; }
        public DateTime ProducedAt { get; set; }
    }

public class ProductDetailsRequestDTOValidator : AbstractValidator<ProductDetailsRequestDTO>
    {
        public ProductDetailsRequestDTOValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(r => r.ArticleGroup).NotEmpty().WithMessage("custom message");
            RuleFor(r => r.ProducedAt).NotEmpty().WithMessage("custom message");
        }
    }

 // FluentValidation setup 
        config.Services.Add(typeof(System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidatorProvider), new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider());
```

From where does fluentvalidation know my created validators and why is my model always true?

Comment: Maybe because both of those types have default values which aren't empty. So `int` is always instantiated with `0`. It isn't a nullable type. Same with `DateTime`. Have you tried saying `.MoreThan(0)` or equivalent.

Comment: MoreThan does not exist in my intellisense. From the documentation: NotEmpty Validator

Description: Ensures that the specified property is not null, an empty string or whitespace (or the default value for value types, eg 0 for int)

Comment: Your Model have 2 properties, they are integer and DateTime types, they can't empty, default of integer is 0 and DateTime is MinValue of Date

Comment: @trungtin1710 Have you read my comment from docu? It says "eg 0 for int" is from NotEmpty()

Comment: @Pascal Sorry for this, now I can see your comment about this document

Comment: It does not even work for an empty string, so my SETUP is wrong I also REPLACED the provider and the f... documenation of fluent validation says nothing about how to configure it.

Comment: @Pascal - You're right that the rules are correct and you interpreted them correctly. I've run a quick test explicitly newing up a validator and running your DTO through it and it does return errors for both the rules so the issue lies in config. Not sure what exactly is wrong with that but that kinda rules out the implementation of your rules themselves as being a culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was but a typo. Your model is decorated with the wrong type name. Instead of decorating it like so:

```
[Validator(typeof(ProductDetailsRequestDTO))]
public class ProductDetailsRequestDTO
{
    public int ArticleGroup { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProducedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Decorate it with the type of your validator:

```
[Validator(typeof(ProductDetailsRequestDTOValidator))]
public class ProductDetailsRequestDTO
{
    public int ArticleGroup { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProducedAt { get; set; }
}
```